# ¿Cómo contar las filas devueltas de una funcion MAX en SQL?

Tags: sql-server

¿Cómo puedo contar el número de filas que me devuelve esta consulta?

```
SELECT MAX(FECHA_INGRESO) FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS
                  WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE'
                  GROUP BY FOLIO
                  HAVING FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190'
```

En consola me muestra dos registros pero como tal el número 2 quiero asignarlo a una variable

---

Mira @Patricio Moracho, lo que tengo es esto:

```
SELECT MAX(FECHA_INGRESO) FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS
WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE'
GROUP BY FOLIO
HAVING FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190'

SELECT @@rowcount
```

Y en la primer consulta me imprime :

> 2017-10-25 11:07:44.730
>   2017-10-30 02:43:25.520

Y en la segunda consulta me imprime: `2`

Y ese número 2 que me imprime, necesito asignarlo a una variable pero cuando lo hago así:

```
SET @RESULTADO = (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)
PRINT @RESULTADO
```

Entonces me imprime solo los datos de la primer consulta y no me imprime el  valor de la variable que debería tener el número `2`.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(MAX(FECHA_INGRESO))  AS total  FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS
                  WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE'
                  GROUP BY FOLIO
                  HAVING FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190';`

Comment: No funciona, me arroja un mensaje de error: No es posible usar una función de agregado con una expresión que contiene un agregado o una subconsulta.

Comment: En lugar de `SET @RESULTADO = (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)` puedes usar `SELECT @RESULTADO = @@ROWCOUNT`

Answer (score 0):

Primero vamos a responder tu pregunta, si quieres incorporar la cantidad de registros de tu consulta a una variable, puedes hacer una subconsulta de esta forma:

```
DECLARE @Cantidad INT
SELECT @Cantidad = COUNT(1)
       FROM (SELECT MAX(FECHA_INGRESO) AS 'MAX_FECHA' 
                  FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS
                  WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE'
                  GROUP BY FOLIO
                  HAVING FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190
        ) T
```

**Edición**: Por tu comentario estas queriendo contar usando `@@ROWCOUNT` lo cual no esta mal pero hay que ser cuidadoso y hacerlo inmediatamente después de la operación que te interesa contar. Si tu haces esto:

```
SELECT MAX(FECHA_INGRESO) FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE' GROUP BY FOLIO HAVING FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190'

SELECT @@rowcount

SET @RESULTADO = (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT) 
PRINT @RESULTADO
```

El segundo @@ROWCOUNT estará contando los registros de la sentencia `SELECT @@rowcount` que es justamente 1. Deberías hacerlo así:

```
SELECT MAX(FECHA_INGRESO) FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE' GROUP BY FOLIO HAVING FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190'
SET @RESULTADO = (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT) 
PRINT @RESULTADO
```

Ahora te hago algunas observaciones, en primer lugar, permiteme una pequeña modificación recomendable:

```
SELECT FOLIO, MAX(FECHA_INGRESO) 
       FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS
       WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE'
             AND FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190'          
       GROUP BY FOLIO
```

Como verás el filtro de `FOLIO` lo coloco a nivel del `WHERE` es mejor filtrar antes de agrupar por cuestiones de performance.

En segundo lugar, lo que básicamente estas recuperando es una fecha máxima de cada `FOLIO` comprendido entre los valor indicados en el filtro y si luego lo que buscas es contar la cantidad de registros, lo que en realidad estas haciendo es ver la cantidad de `FOLIO` distintos, lo cual podrías también resolver así:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FOLIO)
       FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS
       WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE'
             AND FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190'          
       GROUP BY FOLIO
```

Comment: @ErickMartinez, revisa lo último que he editado, explica el comportamiento del `@@rowcount`

Comment: Te entiendo perfecto, solo que el problema es que cuando pongo:

SET @RESULTADO = (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)

No me muestra el valor al imprimir la variable RESULTADO

Comment: @ErickMartinez, por las dudas prueba hacer un `SELECT @RESULTADO` en vez de un `PRINT` a ver si eso soluciona tu problema. Saludos

Comment: no funcionó tampoco, pero lo que hice como ultima opción (no muy viable), cree una tabla temporal, inserté los datos con la consulta, realicé el Count al campo de la tabla y guarde el dato en una variable.

Answer (score 0):

La idea para poder sacar la solución seria trabajar la consulta el max() dentro de lo que vendría a ser la tabla del cual pretendes contar los elementos. Al trabajar de esta forma, esa tabla tiene que tener un alias. La consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
select count(*)
from 
(
SELECT MAX(fechaIngreso) FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS
                  WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE'
                  GROUP BY FOLIO
                  HAVING FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190'
) as tabla;
```

Y el resultado seria este:

```
MariaDB [qwerty]> select count(*)
    -> from
    -> (
    -> SELECT MAX(fechaIngreso) FROM PRESTAMOSFOLIOS
    ->                   WHERE ESTADO = 'DISPONIBLE'
    ->                   GROUP BY FOLIO
    ->                   HAVING FOLIO BETWEEN '155' AND '190'
    -> ) as tabla;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Aclaro que la prueba la hice en MySql, pero es compatible con SQL Server, la lógica es propia del Lenguaje Estructurado de Consultas en general.

Comment: Considera que el OP usa SQL Server, solo para revisar I la consulta es totalmente compatible

Comment: Perdon, me olvide aclarar eso... si es compatible con sql server